# Compiling C code (netcat) to native Android executable

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, native

I'm writing a bash script that uses Netcat to serve framebuffer over network connection, but first I need to compile it to native executable. I even got this script to work on a Ubuntu machine, where netcat is installed by default.

I found this https://github.com/android/platform_external_netcat but have no experience in NDK at all. This obviously doesn't use JNI or Java at all so default approach for making Android applications won't get me anywhere.

So the question is. How do I get an executable file from this source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a good tutorial on Android NDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375453/looking-for-a-good-tutorial-on-android-ndk)

Comment: not really. I want to get an ARM executable. Not .apk package.

Comment: There is proably already a compiled copy of netcat (nc) on the device.

Comment: Weirdly enough, no. That was the first thing I tried. I have ping by default on my 2.3.3 Galaxy S, but not netcat.

Comment: If you have a /system/xbin directory it may be in there, and not on your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the Android sdk under docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html it describes how to use the ndk as standalone compiler which can produce arm binaries.

Comment: That's pretty much it, thanks ;) Also as I found out just now, BusyBox has, among others, netcat inside ;)

Answer (score 3):

If anybody else wants to know, this is from the NDK documentation:

```
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-<level>/arch-<arch>/
export CC="$NDK/toolchains/<name>/prebuilt/<system>/bin/<prefix>gcc --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
$CC -o foo.o -c foo.c
```

More specifically, for the netcat from https://github.com/android/platform_external_netcat

```
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
CC=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYSROOT
$CC -DANDROID -c -o atomicio.o atomicio.c
$CC -DANDROID -c -o netcat.o netcat.c
$CC -o netcat atomicio.o netcat.o
```

Replace the paths from SYSROOT and CC as appropriate.