# Libav build for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, libav

Does anyone succeed compiling Libav for Android. I currently looking for documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes but I can't find any documentation about it. Did I miss something?

Comment: For building with the NDK see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638778/ndk-api-reference-docs and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168303/compiling-c-code-netcat-to-native-android-executable/6168414#6168414

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need help for using the ndk. I know how to build JNI code for Android. I've got issues building Libav.

Comment: If you you trying to build it under Windows - it's not possible at all, unfortunately. As is C compiler named arm-linux-androideabi doesn't exist on WIndows (Cygwin).